# Docker-compose server unreachable

Tags: docker

I am developing a web with this directory scheme:

```
.
├── api
│   ├── here is my backend application
│   └── Dockerfile,
├── client
│   ├── here is my frontend application
│   └── Dockerfile
├── docker-compose
```

I have frontend in NuxtJS with this Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json /app

RUN npm install

COPY . /app

RUN npm run build

ENV HOST 0.0.0.0
EXPOSE 3000

# start command
CMD [ "npm", "start"]
```

My backend is strapi with this Dockerfile:

```
FROM strapi/base:latest

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json /app

# install
RUN npm install

COPY . /app

# RUN rm yarn.lock
# RUN npm
RUN npm run build

ENV HOST 0.0.0.0
EXPOSE 1337

# start command
CMD [ "npm", "start"]
```

And finally this is my docker-compose.yaml file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./client
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./client:/app
      - /app/node_modules
      - /app/.nuxt
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    environment:
      - HOST=0.0.0.0
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      - "backend"

  backend:
    build:
      context: ./api
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./api:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    environment:
      - HOST=0.0.0.0
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
    ports:
      - 1337:1337
```

When I try to build separately both images and then I run them, everything works fine and frontend is able to make calls to backend. But if I try to use docker-compose using `docker-compose up`, both frontend and backend susseccfully start, but backend is unreachable for frontend. Can you please help me what is wrong and why?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is the error you get, and where do you see it?  How do you configure the location of the back-end server?

Comment: Which hostname is your frontend using to try to access the backend? In Compose it is reachable under backend:1337 (= container name). What did you use in your frondend app and how do you start them when running just via docker, where it works?

Comment: This is error I get
Server error:
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

Comment: Yes, backend is reachable under localhost:1337 from my browser

Comment: This is screen from my frontend from page, where I send a request to backend. https://imgur.com/a/fbDJb7V

Other pages where axios request are not used work just fine

Comment: And this is the error in detail https://imgur.com/a/EvxE77l

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compose will start two different Docker containers joining a network (see https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/).

They can access each other via the name you use in the compose file:

- frontend is reachable via http://frontend:3000 for the backend container
- backend via http://backend:1337 for the frontend container

This is different how you access them from the host machine where docker is running. There you can use localhost. From each container you need to use the correct network name.
Because in the frontend container only the frontend is running and listening so there is no one listening on localhost:1337.

Normally you make the backend url configurable via environment variables and use localhost as default for running them locally without docker.
In Docker Compose you need to overwrite the config parameter via the environment section like you did with HOST.

Check your frontend framework how this should be done:
https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-env

Comment: If this helped, please flag the answer as solution. So it is not listed as unanswered question and others directly see that this was the solution. Also I get some Points :).

Comment: Strange thing is this: Strapi uses path /auth/local for login.

http://localhost:1337/auth/local -----> works
http://backend:1337/auth/local ------> doesnt work

Comment: Maybe Strapi is only configured to listen/react to localhost or has some CORS issues. But I do not know Strapi. When the networking is solved and the one container can talk with the other your best try is to check the config of Strapi for hints about Proxies, other host names or to open a new question.

Comment: Or are you using the backend:1337/auth/local from your localhost?